# Flutter local_auth unable to use default system dialog for fingerprint

Tags: android, flutter, fingerprint

I have a problem with Flutter local_auth fingerprint alert dialog.
I need to use a common system view of fingerprint request (images 1-2, it located at the bottom of the screen), but local_auth let me use only this one (image 3, located in the center).
Maybe there is a simple solution close to it, but I still can't find it.
Flutter local_auth: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Images:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The point was in my plugin version. i have imported 0.4, but the last was 0.6.
this last version also uses system default desing, but this default design is updated.
Pay more attention to this, when importing plugins - it can save you a lot of time